# Backbone.js fetch unknown error

Tags: backbone.js

I'm facing an issue with my backbone.js app: I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON webservice, the GET HTTP request is successfull (i had a look in the developer console of chrome) but backbone fetch trigger an error and doesn't update the model.

You can have a look here to the code:
https://github.com/tdurand/faq-app-client-mobile

And you can run the app and try to debug here:
http://tdurand.github.com/faq-app-client-mobile/

The JSON Feed is like this

```
[
    {
       "title":"Probleme ou Bug",
       "desc":"Pour les problemes ou les bugs rencontrés",
       "entries":[
           {
             "title":"testdqs",
             "desc":"testqsdqs"
           }
        ]
    }
]
```

My collection model is:

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({

url:"http://cryptic-eyrie-7716.herokuapp.com/faq/fr",

model:Category,

parse:function(response) {
    console.log("test")
    console.log(response);
    return response;
},

sync: function(method, model, options) {
    var params = _.extend({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: model.url,
        processData:false
    }, options);

    return $.ajax(params);
},
```

});

And my view:

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#index',

initialize:function() {
    Categories.fetch({
        success: function(m,r){
          console.log("success");
          console.log(r); // => 2 (collection have been populated)
        },
        error: function(m,r) {
          console.log("error");
          console.log(r.responseText);
        }
    });
    Categories.on( 'all', this.render, this );
},

//render the content into div of view
render: function(){
  //this.el is the root element of Backbone.View. By default, it is a div.
  //$el is cached jQuery object for the view's element.
  //append the compiled template into view div container
  this.$el.html(_.template(indexViewTemplate,{categories:Categories}));
  //Trigger jquerymobile rendering
  $("#index").trigger('pagecreate');

  //return to enable chained calls
  return this;
}
});
return IndexView;
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

My backend server (with play! framework), was not rendering JSONP properly

This is the code i now use to do it if someone has the same issue.

```
    //Render JSONP
    if (request.params._contains("callback")) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String out = gson.toJson(categoryJSON(categories,lang));

        renderText(request.params.get("callback") + "(" + out + ")");

     } else {

        renderJSON(categoryJSON(categories,lang));

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you're not making an instance of your collection anywhere. Javascript isn't really object oriented and it has this weird functions-as-classes and `prototype` -inheritance type of deal that can confuse anyone coming from the OO -world.

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend...
```

What happens above is that you extend the Backbone `Collection`'s (which is a function) prototype properties with the object (or dictionary) you define. To be able to instantiate this 'class' to an object, you need to use the `new` keyword. You don't do this, so you are calling the function `fetch` of the 'class' `Categories`, which will produce unexpected results.

So instantiate your collection before fetching:

```
initialize:function() {
    this.collection = new Categories(); // instantiate the collection

    // also set event handlers before producing events
    this.collection.on( 'all', this.render, this );

    this.collection.fetch({
        success: function(m,r){
          console.log("success");
          console.log(r); // => 2 (collection have been populated)
        },
        error: function(m,r) {
          console.log("error");
          console.log(r.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, i use requirejs so i'm making an instance of Categories at the end of the module.

You can see the complete code of the view here: https://github.com/tdurand/faq-app-client-mobile/blob/master/views/category.js , i can assure you Categories is instanciated.

I've tried the same code fetching a local json file, and it worked...

Comment: in your github link, you _don't_ initialize the collection. try changing line 31 to return new CategoryView ... unless you meant https://github.com/tdurand/faq-app-client-mobile/blob/master/models/Categories.js

Comment: My bad, i initialize the collection here (the last line): https://github.com/tdurand/faq-app-client-mobile/blob/master/models/Categories.js

And then i load the module this the instanciated collection in my view

Comment: When browsing the page, there is a loading error on jmqr module which is then used to define the router. I would start by eliminating that error which probably doesn't help ...

Comment: Yep, i just pushed the new version without error with the router: http://tdurand.github.com/faq-app-client-mobile

Comment: I'm really stuck with this issue... The request is successfull but the problem seems to be on the callback...